# Evaluating an integral in R3

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, change-of-variable

I am trying to evalute this integral: $$
\int_{A} x^{m} y^{n} z^{p}(1-x-y-z)^{q}|d x \wedge d y \wedge d z|
$$

A=R3 , x , y and z are positive and x+y+z<=1

I used the change of values u=x+y+z , v=(z+y)/u and $\omega$=z/(y+z)
which gave me x=u(1-v) y=vu(1-$\omega$) and z=uv$\omega$

The det of the matrix of the change of variables is: u^2*v

However, I am struggling to find the boundries for u, v and $\omega$ and carrying the calculation.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Changing variables is going to make your life unpleasant, as of the four sides on your figure, three of them are already constants in Cartesian coordinates.

Comment: Thank you. It was actually what the problem advised to do so I tried to do that in hope it will help.